# if /else condition inside foreach

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am developing an angular project.
I have a table file I want to compare each element with a data value if it is correct I will do statement else I will do another comportement but my problem is that even the data is correct it always fetches all the table and should access in the else for a very short time.
How to avoid that, please.

Here is my code:

```
if (this.data) {
  this.imgNotFoundText = '';
  this.data.package.files.forEach(element => {
    i++;
    this.picture = '';
    if (element.name == this.data.properties.Name) {
      this.picture = 'picOne.png'
    }
    if (i == this.data.package.files.length && this.picture == '') {
      this.picture = './../assets/img/notFound.jpg'
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: *"it always fetch all the table and should access in the else for a very short time"* There is no `else` in your code...?

Comment: When asking for help, it's best to indent your code in a consistent, fairly standard way, as it helps people read and understand your code. (It's useful when you're *not* asking for help, too.)

Comment: the else is the second if

Comment: Separately: It seems suspect to always do `this.picture = '';` unconditionally in the loop. If you're going to do that, you may as well only look at the last entry in the array. You probably want to move that to *before* the `forEach` call.

Comment: No, there's a big difference between two `if`s in a row and `if`/`else if`.

Comment: even i did else if i had the same result :/

Comment: @Mat Can you post the stackBlitz Example?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Answer (score 5):

I see a couple of possible problems:

1. It seems suspect to always do `this.picture = '';` unconditionally in the loop. If you're going to do that, you may as well only look at the last entry in the array. You probably want to move that to *before* the `forEach` call.
2. You've referred to an `else`, but there is no `else` in your code. You have two `if`s in a row, but the result of the first `if` doesn't have any effect at all on the second one. You may have wanted `else if`. Then, the second `if` isn't performed if the condition in the first `if` was true.

So if both of those guesses are right:

```
if (this.data) {
    this.imgNotFoundText = '';
    this.picture = '';
    this.data.package.files.forEach(element => {
        i++;
        if (element.name == this.data.properties.Name) {
            this.picture = 'picOne.png'
        } else if (i == this.data.package.files.length && this.picture == '') {
            this.picture = './../assets/img/notFound.jpg'
        }
    });
}
```

---

Side note: You haven't shown how `i` is initialized, but if it's used to track the index of the current entry of the `forEach`, there's no need: `forEach` receives that as a second argument:

```
if (this.data) {
    this.imgNotFoundText = '';
    this.picture = '';
    this.data.package.files.forEach((element, index) => {
    // -----------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        if (element.name == this.data.properties.Name) {
            this.picture = 'picOne.png'
        } else if (index == this.data.package.files.length && this.picture == '') {
    // ------------^^^^^
            this.picture = './../assets/img/notFound.jpg'
        }
    });
}
```

You also might want to avoid that second `if` altogether, by just specifying the "not found" default before the loop:

```
if (this.data) {
    this.imgNotFoundText = '';
    const {files} = this.data.package;
    this.picture = files.length ? './../assets/img/notFound.jpg' : '';
    files.forEach(element => {
        if (element.name == this.data.properties.Name) {
            this.picture = 'picOne.png'
        }
    });
}
```

In that I've assumed `this.picture` should be `''` if there are no entries in `files`, or the "not found" image if there's at least one entry. The loop will overwrite it if it finds a match.

Continuing from there, unless there can be multiple entries in `files` with the same `name`, you probably want to stop as of the first match. So:

```
if (this.data) {
    this.imgNotFoundText = '';
    const {files} = this.data.package;
    this.picture = files.length ? './../assets/img/notFound.jpg' : '';
    for (const {name} of files) {
        if (name == this.data.properties.Name) {
            this.picture = 'picOne.png'
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your goal is but you're just iterating through the list and setting the picture value every time, this means you'll have as result the last element's picture value.

If your goal is to display a "not found" picture for elements who don't have files, you need to have an array of pictures that reflects the array of files (or add a property picture to each file).

Comment: my problem that even i have a file the notFound picture is displayed for a short time then the right picture displayed

Comment: This suggests that you should use a temporary variable to storing the result, and assign it to `this.picture` only after the cycle is done. Also a `break` statement at the first successful result should be used as in previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
if (this.data) {
  this.imgNotFoundText = '';
  this.picture = this.data.package.files.some(
  (element) => element.name === this.data.properties.Name
  ) ? 'picOne.png' : './../assets/img/notFound.jpg'
}
```

It'll return `picOne.png` if any of the items in data.package.files has a name that is same as this.data.properties.Name or it'll return `notFound.jpg`

Although that could